# Group SMS in Twilio

Tags: twilio

Is there a way create a group SMS with the twilio API, just like how I can send an SMS to two contacts on my phone and have the conversation saved in one chat log?

Basically if I have an SMS sent to a twilio number and another person could twilio see that it was sent to them as well as the other person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to send one message to multiple recipients with a single request. you can send only one single SMS with one request. So you can iterate through the array of phone numbers to send SMS.